# What does "typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type" mean?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, iterator, dependent-name

This is the example-implementation of the count algorithm from https://devdocs.io/cpp/algorithm/count_if:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    count(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My question is, what is the significance of `typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type`?
If I were implementing this, I would have simply used `unsigned int` to keep track of the count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you cannot know the best sufficiently-large type the difference between two iterators without knowing anything about the iterators.
As an example, what if the iterator iterates the bytes in a file:
The filesize is 64bit, but we are in a 32bit process. `std::size_t` won't work, likely `unsigned` won't either.

Thus, ask `std::iterator_traits` to generically provide a suitable type.

Now, we have to use `typename` there to assure the compiler that the [dependent qualified name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type` will be a type. That is important to clarify for 2-phase lookup.

Comment: So you're saying that unsigned int might not be large enough to hold the count?

Comment: It might not be enough. It might also be more than needed.

Answer (score 0):

typename tells the compiler that iterator_traits::difference_type is of type class.

Consider an easier to understand example:

```
class ...
{
    typename T::Something *p;
}
```

Without the typename, the compiler may try to create a static member which will contain the result of T::Something multiplied by p;

while when you state typename, the compiler is certain to know that p is a pointer of type T::Something

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is more about "`difference_type`" than "`typename`". (Note the "If I were implementing this" part of the question.)